# HTML change element via Form submission

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Hi I am relatively new to JavaScript and have encountered a problem whilst creating a webpage for a project.
I have a table which looks like the following:

```
<div class = "frame3" id = "frame3">
        <table id = "info_table" style = "width:100%">
            <tr>
                <th>Linie</th>
                <th>Start Datum</th> 
                <th>End Datum</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id = "linie">24</td>
                <td id = "start">01.02.2020</td>
                <td id = "end">01.02.2020</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

And I have a Form which looks like the following:

```
<div class = "searchbar" id = "searchbar">
        <form onSubmit = "return process();">
            
            <label for = "label">Linie:</label>
            <input type = "number" id = "label" placeholder = "Linie">
            
            <label for = "time_start">Von:</label>
            <input type = date id = "time_start" name = "time_start">
            
            <label for = "time_start">Bis:</label>
            <input type = date id = "time_end" name = "time_end">

            <input type = "submit" id = "submit">
        </form>
    </div>
```

I want the Form submission to replace the elements in the table. My idea is the following, however upon submission, there is no change.
If anyone knows what I missed that would be great!

```
function process(){
        document.getElementById("linie").innerHTML = document.getElementById("label").value;
        document.getElementById("start").innerHTML = document.getElementById("time_start").value;
        document.getElementById("end").innerHTML = document.getElementById("time_end").value;
    };
```

Comment: Write a logger in the process function to be sure it's being called.  We don't know how you're getting your JS.  Also log your left and right hand operands so you know you're actually getting the element from the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your function is getting called your DOM is probably changing correctly, but the page is refreshing afterwards, in order to prevent the default behaviour you need to `return false;`. The below is working:

```js
function process() {
  document.getElementById("linie").innerHTML = document.getElementById("label").value;
  document.getElementById("start").innerHTML = document.getElementById("time_start").value;
  document.getElementById("end").innerHTML = document.getElementById("time_end").value;
  return false;
};
```

```html
<div class="frame3" id="frame3">
  <table id="info_table" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <th>Linie</th>
      <th>Start Datum</th>
      <th>End Datum</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="linie">24</td>
      <td id="start">01.02.2020</td>
      <td id="end">01.02.2020</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<form onSubmit="return process();">

  <label for="label">Linie:</label>
  <input type="number" id="label" placeholder="Linie">

  <label for="time_start">Von:</label>
  <input type=d ate id="time_start" name="time_start">

  <label for="time_start">Bis:</label>
  <input type=d ate id="time_end" name="time_end">

  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
</div>
```